# Looping a list of related items

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to print a list of products related to the product whose page they're displayed in. The sorting criteria are the product tags.

But the loop is giving me aches. How can I change the code below to have it to print one list of products matching the tags altogether?

```
<?php $wpsc_product_tags = get_the_product_tags( wpsc_the_product_id() );
if ($wpsc_product_tags) {
foreach ($wpsc_product_tags as $wpsc_product_tag) {
$tagname[] = $wpsc_product_tag->name;
echo do_shortcode( "[wpsc_products tag='" . echo implode($tagname) . "']");
}
else
{ echo 'No tags exist for this product.';
} ?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `echo`-oart out of the loop:

```
$tagnames = array();

foreach( (array) get_the_product_tags( wpsc_the_product_id() ) as $wpsc_product_tag )
{
    $tagnames[] = $wpsc_product_tag->name;
}

if( !empty( $tagnames ) )
{
    echo do_shortcode( "[wpsc_products tag='" . implode( ',', $tagnames ) . "']" );
}
else
{
    echo '<p class="error">No tags exist for this product.</p>';
}
```

Comment: Dreamweaver prompts an error on the "echo do_shortcode..." line.

Comment: Yeah, maybe because I've copied the second `echo` too. Since when is Dreamweaver an IDE for PHP development? I thought it to be an crappy piece of software to generate HTML websites? (At least it used to be in first years of this centruy…)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code is working. :) I'm not a php developer. Can you suggest a valuable IDE? I don't seem to be able to get Dreamweaver to be explicit about errors. It just says that there's an error on that line. Thank you.